# Should I disable cups, lvm2-lvmpolld and lvm2-monitor?

Tags: lvm, opensuse, cups

I am using the Cinnamon Desktop Environment in OpenSuSe Tumbleweed, btrfs with grub snapshots without lvm. I don't need to use a printer. Will disabling these services cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I disable cups, lvm2-lvmpolld and lvm2-monitor?

Not really.

While cups might actually use a token amount of RAM, the other two are really small programs, that just

- sleep until someone starts polling info about LVM, or
- sleep until the kernel notices anything changing about LVM configuration and wakes them up.

Neither happens.

> Will disabling these services cause problems?

Blivet-gui might be a bit confused about the lack of LVM infrastructure. But I don't think it will misbehave.

Disabling cups might make browsers, text editors and the like fall back to strange prehistoric defaults. I don't think it has any worth trying this out. I could even see that service being automatically started (and a requirement) for some desktop environments or tools, so "disabling" might not actually be possible.

You're running a desktop environment. Small services like CUPS and LVM daemons really cost you negligibly little RAM, and no CPU time at all. Unless you have an incredibly slow medium from which you run, the boot time difference of not starting these should be in the milliseconds.

So, I honestly wouldn't do it.